# How to parse the json object with multiple keys in android

Tags: java, android, json

I want to put the JSON result in textviews but because of multiple array i can get only one key/value of datetime, location and status objects. The json object is:

```
{  
   "signature":"testSignature",
   "deliverydate":"2015-08-06 15:07:00",
   "datetime":{  
      "0":1438848420,
      "1":1438841820,
      "2":1438838760,
   },
   "location":{  
      "0":"PA",
      "1":"PA",
      "2":"PA",
   },
   "status":{  
      "0":"packed",
      "1":"On the go",
      "2":"delivered",
   },
   "pickupdate":2015-08-04 07:55:00
}
```

and this is my java code:

```
try {

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NO", NUMBER_TO_POST));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_TO_POST, "POST", params);

    success = json.getString(TAG_SIGNATURE);
    if (success != null) {
        SIGNATURE = json.getString(TAG_SIGNATURE);
        DELIVERY_DATE = json.getString(TAG_DELIVERY_DATE);

        JSONObject DT = json.getJSONObject(TAG_DATETIME);
        DATETIME = DT.getString("0");

        JSONObject LOC = json.getJSONObject(TAG_LOCATION);
        LOCATION = LOC.getString("0");

        JSONObject STAT = json.getJSONObject(TAG_STATUS);
        STATUS = STAT.getString("0");

        PICKUP_DATE = json.getString(TAG_PICKUP_DATE);

    }else{
        finish();

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library to parse JSONs.

And to be a bit more helpful, here is how your class to hold JSON values might look like:

```
class MyClassForGsonToHoldParseJSON {  
    String signature;
    String deliverydate;
    Map<String, long> datetime;
    Map<String, String> location;
    Map<String, String> status;
    String pickupdate;
}
```

Then just use something like this to conver variable `json` with JSON data to an object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyClassForGsonToHoldParseJSON f = gson.fromJson(json, MyClassForGsonToHoldParseJSON.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON format is wrong:

```
{
    "signature": "testSignature",
    "deliverydate": "2015-08-06 15:07:00",
    "datetime": {
        "0": 1438848420,
        "1": 1438841820,
        "2": 1438838760
    },
    "location": {
        "0": "PA",
        "1": "PA",
        "2": "PA"
    },
    "status": {
        "0": "packed",
        "1": "On the go",
        "2": "delivered"
    },
    "pickupdate": " 2015-08-04 07:55:00"
}
```

Comment: The last sentence should be double quotes Json